# Starting IE with runas

Tags: windows-7, command-line, internet-explorer

I want to run an IE shortcut, as another user and starting a specific site. With the following Target command line:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:Domain\Account@Domain "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

I get a cmd password window, that after logon will start IE ad domain admin. With the following target command line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://www.google.com
```

I get IE starting as standard user and on the specific site.

Now for my obvious question

How can I incorporate the two ? The target command line

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:domain\user@domain "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" www.google.com
```

does not work. :( Appreciate any answer or ideas

Comment: Besides mario's answer, another option may be to make a batch file, and run a batch file, instead.  That can simplify things if you ever need to use a more complicated command.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit tricky. With your current command line you've passed `www.google.com` as a parameter to `runas`. To get it to notice it as being part of the command line, you'll have to add quotes and escape the ones around the path. Also note that you can pick one of two user/domain notations, not both at once!

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:domain\user "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe\" www.google.com"
```

This will cause the final parameters to stick together (`runas` will receive them as one parameter rather than two).